# Is there anything special about the Borderlands 2 GOTY edition over the base game with the same DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2, version-differences

At some point many moons ago, I purchased Borderlands 2 with the season pass. Right now, it seems the only things included in the GOTY bundle I don't already have are:

- Mechromancer class,
- Psycho class,
- Collector's Edition pack,
- Creature Slaughterdome dlc.

At this exact moment in time, I can buy the GOTY edition for $9.99, or I can buy the individual components for $9.86 total. I'm not hugely concerned about 13¢, but the nerd in me is curious if there's any distinction between the vanilla game + DLC and the GOTY game with its included DLC (other than price, of course). For example:

- A big label on the main menu saying "Game of the Year Editon",
- Differences in versioning,
- Differences in gameplay,
- Differences in the UI,
- An achievement for playing the GOTY version.

I don't have any of the headhunter packs, or the purely cosmetic DLC, but since those aren't included with the GOTY bundle, I'm ignoring them entirely for this discussion. However, if there's some distinction between vanilla and GOTY in one of those packs, it would be a useful answer even if I don't pick them up myself.

I'm using the PC version of the game, though it could still be useful to have answers for other systems if those answers are different.

Answer (score 3):

For the GOTY Edition, you get these additions:

> With the Borderlands 2 Game of the Year Edition, players can experience every epic boss battle, increase the level for each of the six playable Vault Hunters, play all of the additional campaign content, and enjoy hundreds of hours of shoot-and-loot mayhem at an extraordinary value. The Game of the Year Edition contains over $100 of gameplay content and includes:
>
> Borderlands 2 Main Game;
>   Captain Scarlett and her Pirate's Booty;
>   Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage;
>   Sir Hammerlock's Big Game Hunt;
>   Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep;
>   Creature Slaughter Dome;
>   Premiere Club Content:
>   Gaige, the Mechromancer Character Class;
>   Gearbox Gun Pack;
>   Golden Key;
>   Vault Hunter's Relic;
>   Krieg, the Psycho Character Class;
>   Collector's Edition Heads and Skins;
>   Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 1.

[Sauce](http://www.gamestop.com/xbox-360/games/borderlands-2-game-of-the-year-edition/111617)

So, to answer you question.  It's slightly different.  More classes more achievements

Answer (score -1):

The GOTY Edition is just a bundle with the game and a bunch of DLCs

Comment: Hey K. Reffler.  Try to be more elaborate with your answers.  Maybe include a source that compares the GOTY edition to a base game with the DLCs.  Perhaps there is a slight difference that we otherwise wouldn't be able to determine from this answer.